# how do i get list with lookup columns and managed metadata columns in sharepoint site collection using CSOM/PNP?

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, pnp-powershell

we need to create a powershell script which gives us lists which all have lookup column or managed meta data column using CSOM powershell or PNP

and finally we need to export the output to either csv/xml

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Please provide any code chunk you have tried so far to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 0):

To get all list which has Lookup columns using powershell.

Powershell to get list column and its types

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

#Configuration Parameters
$SiteURL="http://sp:12001"
$ListName= "Customers"
$CSVPath="C:\Lee\script\list.csv"

#Get the Web and List
$Web = Get-SPWeb $SiteURL
$List = $Web.Lists.TryGetList($ListName)

#Export List Fields to CSV file
$List.Fields | select Title, InternalName,Type | Export-Csv -path $CSVPath -NoTypeInformation
```

Another link doing same for all sites in farm
https://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2015/04/powershell-finding-all-sharepoint-lists.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:+TechTrainingNotes+(Mike+Smith%27s+Tech+Training+Notes)

you have to use above snipped and change as per you requirement, you won't get any ready made solution. Above link and snipped will give you idea on how to get started.

Comment: The user has tagged the question with "SharePoint Online" so CSOM, PNP or SP Online module is required.